# C++-CLI wrapping a set of members

Tags: c#, c++-cli

In C++ I have something of the sort:

```
    class Params{
    int X;
    double Y;
    SomeEnum E;
    ......
    }
```

I would like to wrap this in C++\CLI so that a C# user would see a class with the same list of params as getters\setters.

Trouble is I have many Params-like classes and each has quite a lot of params.
Is there a neat way to wrap this, or must I hand copy each parameter?

Comment: I assume you can't just change those classes into `ref class` with public properties, right?

Comment: Depends, can an Enum function both as CLI and native C++?
And how do I handle copying from CLI class to native and vice versa?(I don't think memcpy is safe here)

Answer (score 1):

If your end goal is having both a C++ and a C++/CLI definition for each of your classes (and they're basic POD classes, nothing fancy going on) you could use the preprocessor to your advantage.

```
#ifdef _MANAGED
    #define PARAMS_CLASS(name) ref class name
#else
    #define PARAMS_CLASS(name) class name
#endif

PARAMS_CLASS(Params)
{
public:
    int X;
    double Y;
    SomeEnum E;
};
```

Comment: they are POD classes but there's a point in my program where I must convert from one to another and I don't think I can access them both with your way.

Comment: @Leo: You'd want them in different namespaces, a macro can help accomplish that too.

Comment: A project is going to see only one "branch" of the macro at any given time. I still can't see how you can access both. Can you give a code example that converts from native to clr and vice versa elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea. Instead of using :

```
class Params1{
  int X;
  double Y;
}
.
.
.
```

make use of `std::tuple<int,double>` in native code. And at the managed side you will have

```
#include <tuple>

public ref class ManagedParam1
{
std::tuple<int,double> * tmp_ptr;
public:
ManagedParam1( std::tuple<int,double> * ptr ) : tmp_ptr(ptr) {  }
property int intProp 
{
    int get () {return std::get<0>(*tmp_ptr);} 
    void set (int value) {std::get<0>(*tmp_ptr) = value;}
}
property double doubleProp 
{
    double get () {return std::get<1>(*tmp_ptr);} 
    void set (double value) {std::get<1>(*tmp_ptr) = value;}
}

};

public ref class ManagedParam2
{
std::tuple<int,double,int> * tmp_ptr;

public: 
ManagedParam2( std::tuple<int,double,int> * ptr ) : tmp_ptr(ptr) {  }
property int intProp1 
{
    int get () { return std::get<0>(*tmp_ptr); }
    void set(int value) {   std::get<0>(*tmp_ptr) = value;}
}
property double doubleProp 
{
    double get () {return std::get<1>(*tmp_ptr);} 
    void set (double value) {std::get<1>(*tmp_ptr) = value;}
}
property int intProp2 
{
    int get () {return std::get<2>(*tmp_ptr);} 
    void set(int value) {   std::get<2>(*tmp_ptr) = value;}
}
};
```

So you will write N params classes in managed code and 1 (tuple) in native code.

Comment: Those unnamed tuples with over 10 parameters are going to be impossible to deal with on the native C++ side.

Comment: @Leo: You can always `typedef`, you know. `typedef std::tuple<int,double,int> some_tuple;`

Comment: Yes but I'm talking about usage. I'll have to access parameters by number instead of a name which is hard to read and error prone

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a little old by now, but here is my suggestion using makros.

First you write a makro, that defines all you variables/properties. This makro takes another makro as argument:

```
#define VARIABLES(anothermakro) \
    anothermakro( int , X ) \
    anothermakro( double , Y ) \
    anothermakro( SomeEnum , Z )
```

Then you create both classes:

```
ref class ManagedClass 
{
    #define PROPERTY(type, name) property type name;
    VARIABLES( PROPERTY )
    #undef PROPERTY
}
```

and

```
class UnmanagedClass
{
    #define PROPERTY(type, name) type name;
    VARIABLES( PROPERTY )
    #undef PROPERTY
}
```

Then you can also add something like

```
void ManagedClass::assign(UnmanagedClass const & value) 
{
    #define ASSIGN(type, name) this->name = value.name;
    VARIABLES( ASSIGN )
    #undef ASSIGN
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++\Cli wrappers can get messy and tend to need a lot of maintenance time

you could use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to automate the conversion process